# how to prevent react page from rendering twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-18, strict-mode

i am using **react 18  StrictMode** and i have some pages in an application while navigating from one page to another page (using Router) an empty page displaying at first and after 2 3 seconds page refreshing and displaying with data.

example i have pie chart in a page when i navigate to this page empty grid showing at first and after that page reloading and pie chart showing

i tried few ways to prevent it 1. spinner using use state, useRef check and Suspense CallBack but nothing is worked.

**This is my sample code**

**Service.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
//demo code
class Service {

  async fetchData1() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("https//some-end-point");
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error retrieving data:'+ error);
    }
  }

  async fetchData2(){
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("https//some-end-point");
        return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error retrieving data:'+ error);
      }
  }

}
export default new Service();
```

**Dashboard.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Service from '../services/Service';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [BarData, setBarData] = useState([]);
  const [StatsData, setStatsData] = useState([]);
  const [PieData, setPieData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const data1 = await Service.fetchData1();
        const data2 = await Service.fetchData2();
        if (data1) setBarData(data1);
        if (data2) setStatsData(data2);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error fetching data:' + error);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  setPieData([
    {
      label: 'Label A',
      value: StatsData['Total Data A'],
    },
    {
      label: 'Label B',
      value: StatsData['Total Data B'],
    },
  ]);

  const PieDataChart = {
    series: PieData.map(item => item.value),
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      labels: PieData.map(item => item.label),
      //some properties
    },
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="loader">
        <RingLoader color="#36D7B7" loading={true} size={100} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="page-container">
      {/* demo data*/}
      <div className="pieChart-Wrapper">
        <div className="pieChart">
          <ReactApexChart options={PieDataChart.options} series={PieDataChart.series} type="pie" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

i want to render the page only once to prevent the empty rendering at first reload, please help me.

Note: i added some logs in useEffect when navigating from another page to this page one request is made and it returns undefined and after few seconds one request is making and this time it fetching data.

Thanks

Comment: React Strictmode will do this in development mode. It doesn't happen when you build and deploy to production.

My best advice would be to temporarily remove strict mode in your local environment while testing.

Comment: After deployed in apache server only i noticed the issue ,in the production build also am getting same

Answer (score 2):

It might be related to the React StrictMode feature. It was intentionally introduced in order to avoid side effects in render phase.But page renders twice only in development mode, not in production.

Comment: but i found issue in the production build only (apache server)

Comment: even after removing strict mode in development i am getting same issue

ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, hope it help you

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Service from '../services/Service';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [BarData, setBarData] = useState([]);
  const [StatsData, setStatsData] = useState([]);
  const [PieData, setPieData] = useState([
    {
      label: 'Label A',
      value: 0,
    },
    {
      label: 'Label B',
      value: 0,
    },
  ]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const data1 = await Service.fetchData1();
        const data2 = await Service.fetchData2();
        if (data1) setBarData(data1);
        if (data2) setStatsData(data2);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error fetching data:' + error);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (StatsData['Total Data A'] && StatsData['Total Data B']) {
      setPieData([
        {
          label: 'Label A',
          value: StatsData['Total Data A'],
        },
        {
          label: 'Label B',
          value: StatsData['Total Data B'],
        },
      ]);
    }
  }, [StatsData]);

  const PieDataChart = {
    series: PieData.map(item => item.value),
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      labels: PieData.map(item => item.label),
      //some properties
    },
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="loader">
        <RingLoader color="#36D7B7" loading={true} size={100} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="page-container">
      {/* demo data*/}
      <div className="pieChart-Wrapper">
        <div className="pieChart">
          <ReactApexChart options={PieDataChart.options} series={PieDataChart.series} type="pie" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: bro i am thinking problem with routing while navigating at first return undefined and after it returns data means incomplete request. is this causes two times rendering in production mode?

Comment: can you explain what part of this code actually solves the issue ?